# Not able to load table throgh Informatica due to source table is having a column of 0 varchar lenght

Tags: varchar, netsuite, informatica

I am loading data from Netsuite to Oracle through informatica. There is a table in Netsuite which is having a column of wvarchar(). But while converting it shows as varchar of 0 length and  when informatica tries to load that tables, it sees that column of 0 length and throws error. Is there a way to convert from wvarchar() to varchar() on Netsuite side or can we identify throgh informatica?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue. The same issue exists when importing a varchar(max) port.
As a simple solution you can just redefine this value in source definition manually to varchar(1000),  for example.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me to solve this issue